# I am trying to draw a stacked group bar chart using pgfplots. Unfortunately, the rightmost bar is not rendered

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
 \caption{Test Caption}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every axis/.style={
    ybar stacked,
    ymin=0,ymax=100,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    x tick label style={
       % add some negative yshift to move ticklabels down
       yshift=-10mm,
       xshift=5mm,
       %rotate=45,
       anchor=east},
  x axis line style = { opacity = 0 }, 
  y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
  tickwidth = 0pt,
  width=8cm,
  height=6cm,
  % symbolic coords have numerical distance of 1
  % so with the following line you get a tick at every symbolic coord
  xtick distance=1,
  symbolic x coords={
      A,
      B,
      C,
    },
  bar width=8pt
  },
]

\pgfplotsset{
  % define a new style used for the plot used to add labels
  % 2 args means it takes two mandatory arguments, so must be used as
  % labelplot={first arg}{second arg}
  labelplot/.style 2 args={
     % forget plot means it doesn't affect cycle lists or legends
     forget plot,
     % #1 is first argument, the text used in the nodes near coords
     nodes near coords=#1,
     % #2 is second argument, a length that should be the same as the bar shift for the axis
     every node near coord/.style={below,font=\small,xshift=#2,anchor=east,rotate=90}
  }
}
\begin{axis}[bar shift=-10pt, xticklabels={}]
\addplot [labelplot={1st}{-10pt}] coordinates
{(A,0) (B,0) (C,0)};
\addplot coordinates
{(A,64) (B,64) (C,48)};
\addplot coordinates
{(A,12) (B,19) (C,33)};
\addplot coordinates
{(A,24) (B,17) (C,33)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}
\addplot [labelplot={2nd}{0pt}] coordinates
{(A,0) (B,0) (C,0)};
\addplot+[fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,53) (B,28) (C,38)};
\addplot+[fill=red!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,18) (B,19) (C,19)};
\addplot+[fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,30) (B,53) (C,43)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=10pt]
\addplot [labelplot={3rd}{10pt}] coordinates
{(A,0) (B,0) (C,0)};
\addplot+[fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,42) (B,25) (C,33)};
\addplot+[fill=red!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,19) (B,27) (C,20)};
\addplot+[fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,39) (B,48) (C,47)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=20pt,xticklabels={}]
\addplot [labelplot={4th}{20pt}] coordinates
{(A,0) (B,0) (C,0)};
\addplot+[fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,42) (B,25) (C,40)};
\addplot+[fill=red!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,19) (B,27) (C,20)};
\addplot+[fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates
{(A,39) (B,48) (C,40)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

- With your code nodes below each stack bars doesn't show up as you show on image in the question, but this was not your question :-)
- with adding `enlarge x limits=0.25,` to the every axis style and change accordingly `xshift` for bar positions you can obtain:

[image]

Changes in MWE (Minimal Working Example) below in comparison to yours are marked by `% <---`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \caption{Test Caption}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every axis/.style={
    width=8cm,  height=6cm,
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=8pt,
    xtick style = {draw=none},          %<---
    x tick label style={yshift=-10mm},  %<---
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ymin=0,ymax=100,
  % symbolic coords have numerical distance of 1
  % so with the following line you get a tick at every symbolic coord
    xtick distance=1,
    symbolic x coords={A, B, C},
    enlarge x limits=0.25, % <--- added
                    }]
\pgfplotsset{                    
  % define a new style used for the plot used to add labels
  % 2 args means it takes two mandatory arguments, so must be used as
  % labelplot={first arg}{second arg}
  labelplot/.style 2 args={
     % forget plot means it doesn't affect cycle lists or legends
     %forget plot,
     % #1 is first argument, the text used in the nodes near coords
     nodes near coords=#1,
     % #2 is second argument, a length that should be the same as the bar shift for the axis
     every node near coord/.style={below,font=\small,xshift=#2,anchor=east,rotate=90},
                            }
        }
\begin{axis}[bar shift=-15pt]   % <--- changed

\addplot [labelplot={1st}{15pt}] coordinates {(A,0) (B,0) (C,0)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,64) (B,64) (C,48)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,12) (B,19) (C,33)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,24) (B,17) (C,33)};
    \end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=-5pt]   % <--- changed
\addplot [labelplot={2nd}{0pt}] coordinates {(A,0) (B,0) (C,0)};
\addplot+[fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates {(A,53) (B,28) (C,38)};
\addplot+[fill=red!50!gray]  coordinates {(A,18) (B,19) (C,19)};
\addplot+[fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates {(A,30) (B,53) (C,43)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=5pt]   % <--- changed
\addplot [labelplot={3rd}{10pt}] coordinates {(A,0) (B,0) (C,0)};
\addplot+[fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates {(A,42) (B,25) (C,33)};
\addplot+[fill=red!50!gray]  coordinates {(A,19) (B,27) (C,20)};
\addplot+[fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates {(A,39) (B,48) (C,47)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[bar shift=15pt]   % <--- changed
\addplot [labelplot={4th}{20pt}] coordinates {(A,0) (B,0) (C,0)};
\addplot+[fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates {(A,42) (B,25) (C,40)};
\addplot+[fill=red!50!gray]  coordinates {(A,19) (B,27) (C,20)};
\addplot+[fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates   {(A,39) (B,48) (C,40)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Here is a solution where is:

- merged yours `tikzpicture` style option `every axis/.style` and style settings with `\pgfplotsset` in clear and concise common `\pgfplotsset` inserted after `\begin{tikzpicture}`
- are added to all `axis` options settings for `bar width`, `bar shift`
- eliminated multiple overwriting of `xtick` and `yticks` labels by adding of the  `ytick=\empty, xtick=\empty` options to the last three  `axis` options options
- added labels 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th to the each bar stacks by adding code lines:

```
     point meta=explicit symbolic,
     stacked ignores zero=false
```

to the settings in the `\pgfplotsset`.

- labels of stacks are written as options to the first `\addplot` coordinates

Above described changes are marked in the code by `% <---`, and the added code lines, which enables labeling of bar stacks are marked by  `% <===`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \caption{Test Caption}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=8cm,  height=6cm,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,              % <---
    xtick style = {draw=none},          % <---
    x tick label style={yshift=-2em},   % <---
    ytick={0,20,...,100},               
% coordinates
    xtick distance=1,
    symbolic x coords={A, B, C},
    ymin=0, ymax=100,                   
    ybar stacked,
    axis on top,                        % <---
% nodes 
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.style={font=\footnotesize,
                                  below, rotate=90, anchor=east},   % <---
    point meta=explicit symbolic,       % <===
    stacked ignores zero=false          % <===
            }
%%%% diagram body
\begin{axis}[bar width=8pt, 
             bar shift=-15pt]
\addplot [xshift=-15pt] coordinates
    {(A,0) [1st]
     (B,0) [1st]
     (C,0) [1st]
    };
\addplot coordinates {(A,52) (B,28) (C,38)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,18) (B,19) (C,19)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,30) (B,53) (C,43)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ytick=\empty, xtick=\empty,
             bar width=8pt,
             bar shift=-5pt]
\addplot [xshift=-5pt] coordinates
    {(A,0) [2nd]
     (B,0) [2nd]
     (C,0) [2nd]
    };
\addplot [fill=blue!50!gray]   coordinates {(A,52) (B,28) (C,38)};
\addplot [fill=red!50!gray]    coordinates {(A,18) (B,19) (C,19)};
\addplot [fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates {(A,30) (B,53) (C,43)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ytick=\empty, xtick=\empty,
             bar width=8pt,
             bar shift= 5pt]
\addplot [xshift=5pt] coordinates
    {(A,0) [3rd]
     (B,0) [3rd]
     (C,0) [3rd]
    };
\addplot [fill=blue!50!gray]   coordinates {(A,42) (B,25) (C,33)};
\addplot [fill=red!50!gray]    coordinates {(A,19) (B,27) (C,20)};
\addplot [fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates {(A,39) (B,48) (C,47)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ytick=\empty, xtick=\empty,
             bar width=8pt,
             bar shift=15pt]
\addplot [xshift=15pt] coordinates
    {(A,0) [4th]
     (B,0) [4th]
     (C,0) [2nd]
    };
\addplot [fill=blue!50!gray]   coordinates {(A,42) (B,25) (C,40)};
\addplot [fill=red!50!gray]    coordinates {(A,19) (B,27) (C,20)};
\addplot [fill=yellow!50!gray] coordinates {(A,39) (B,48) (C,40)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]